# Need to assign null into condition by CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need help with condition for my query.

I want it to work like this:

```
WHERE 
    [Column] = CASE
                  WHEN @Variable1 IN (1,2) 
                     THEN NULL
                     ELSE @Variable2
               END
```

But it won't work because `[Column] = NULL` is not working on our work sever, SQL Server 2012.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not working means? Whats issue? Did you checked the data?

Comment: If I use [Column] is NULL then I find the data i'm looking for, but if I use  [Column] = NULL then querry returns nothing

Comment: Try `[Column] is NULL and @Variable1 in (1,2) or [Column] = @Variable2`

Comment: You must check NULL but column is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE ISNULL([Column],1) = CASE
                WHEN @Variable1 IN (1,2) THEN  1
                ELSE @Variable2
             END
```

P.S. Change value `1` to any value that not valid for `[Column]`.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM! THANKS

Comment: And when inserting the _magic number_ that can never occur (in two places) add a comment to document what the heck it is doing there. Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.

You have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL operators.
Rewrite your condition:

```
WHERE ([Column] IS NULL AND @Variable1 IN (1,2) 
   OR [Column] = @Variable2)
   AND ...other conditions...
```

Comment: That does not return what I want... IF Variable1 is 1 or 2 then i want to look for entries where column is null , if Variable1 is something else i want to look for entries where column = Variable2

Comment: Do you have other conditions in `WHERE` clause? Can you post data sample and expected output?

Comment: Yes, its someting like WHERE COLUMN 2 = Variable3

Comment: @DavidWaldo Editied my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CASE
  WHEN @Variable1 IN (1,2) AND [Column] IS NULL THEN 1
  WHEN [Column] = @Variable2 THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: The poster would greatly benefit from some *explanation* about why and how this performs what s/he is asking.